# Adding item to ListView on server response

Tags: android, listview

I have a dialog class which creates a dialog with listview in it by calling addDialog() from MainActivity.

```
public class LanDevicesDialog 
{
    public static Dialog dialog;
    public ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    LanDeviceListAdapter adapter = new LanDeviceListAdapter(MainActivity.mContext, array);


    public void addDialog(Context ctx)
    {
        dialog = new Dialog(ctx);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_lan_device_dialog);
        dialog.show();


        ListView listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lan_device_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void updateDialog(String item)
    {
        array.add(item);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public static class LanDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {...}
}
```

I also have a server which sends me data that I want to add to the listview in every its response.

For example, the dialog is opened, a server sends data so now listview has one item. The server sends data again so that listview got 2 items in it.

On server response i call AsyncTask which calls updateDialog() method in onPostExecute().

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
    {
        LanDevicesDialog devicesDialog = new LanDevicesDialog();
        devicesDialog.updateDialog("test");
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
```

**The problem is that the listview is showing nothing at all.**

Answer (score 0):

Build your dialog like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new 
AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
dialogBuilder.setTitle("Choose any");
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String
(YourActivity.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
arrayAdapter.add("One");
arrayAdapter.add("Two");
arrayAdapter.add("Three");
arrayAdapter.add("Four");
arrayAdapter.add("Five");
dialogBuilder.setAdapter(arrayAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);
                AlertDialog.Builder builderInner = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
                builderInner.setMessage(strName);
                builderInner.setTitle("Your Selected Item is");
                builderInner.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                builderInner.show();
            }
        });
dialogBuilder.show(); `
```